# how to render multiple json files during spring boot start up

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to read multiple JSON files at once in a @PostConstruct method.

I gave the path of the parent folder as src/main/resources and I get the file list using the file.listFiles() method.

It worked on Windows but not on Unix. Unix is not able to find the parent folder path for some reason. Any suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: Gave an expected answer, but some code to look at is always helpful :).

Comment: the problem might be in how you mention your file location. always use file.pathSeperator it will give  native path separator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding in Java, always use the forward slash (/) for paths.  This will work on Windows and Linux, etc.  It is OS independent.

Your paths only working on Windows probably means you used () which is Windows-specific.

Note, Windows itself does require () for paths in general, but Java is coded to correctly interpret (/) regardless of underlying OS.

Comment: public class RenderJson { public [] file getFiles() {File f=new File("src/main/resources/jsonsource" );return f. listFiles() } }                                                                Above code wors on Windows but on Unix listFiles method return as empty